# Laravel 6 : Set default value of url link in datatables

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to save data of books with the image URL also in the database. How to set default value URL links in the database? I've tried with string but it turned out to be an error too.

This is the data tables

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('perpuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('author');
        $table->string('location');
        $table->string('publisher');
        $table->string('print_year');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('image_URL'); // sdefault value?
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default()` method on your `image_URL` column like so

```
$table->string('image_URL')->default('your-default-link');
```

You can read more about [Column Modifiers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers)